# How to use a list in a raw django SQL query that uses `WHERE ... IN (...)`?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

How do you inject a list parameter into a Django raw query?

Given a list of UUIDs i'd like to be able to inject them into the `()` in a `WHERE ... IN (...)`
query.

```py
list_of_uuids = [
  "<UUID_1>",
  "<UUID_2>
]
```

Output for SQL:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM some_model_table 
WHERE some_model_table.uuid IN ( "<UUID_1>", "<UUID_2>" )
```

So I tried doing the following using raw django queries:

```
query_set = SomeModel.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM some_model_table where some_model_table.uuid IN %s", [list_of_uuids])
```

Unfortunately, the above will give the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ARRAY":

LINE X: WHERE uuid IN ARRAY['00123...
```

Which means the list is interpreted as an array and passed to the SQL query as an array, which cannot be used in an `IN` query.

Enclosing the injected array in `()` also doesn't work:

```
LINE X: WHERE uuid IN (ARRAY['00123...
                                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**Note: I'm aware this particular example can be done with Django ORM, but my actual query is more complex than this and has to be done with raw queries, and contains this `WHERE ... IN (...)` syntax.** I just kept the irrelevant code out of the question to make it easier to parse. For those who want to use ORM, here is the code you need:

```
query_set = SomeModel.objects.filter(uuid__in=list_of_uuids)
```

I have tried building the delimited list of UUID strings myself and injecting it, unfortunately this is injected in the format `WHERE uuid IN ('"some_uuid", "other_uuid"')`

You *could* use `.format(...)` on the query string before handing it over to Django ORM, but this opens us up to SQL injection.

I've also looked into a way of getting SQL to interpret the Array as the input for the WHERE IN query but I haven't had much luck there.

Is there another way? Could we somehow parse the array given to the SQL into valid syntax for the `WHERE ... IN (...)` query?

Comment: from memory it may depends on which database you use. have you tried to put it in a tuple rather than a list?

Comment: Try `"SELECT * FROM some_model_table where some_model_table.uuid = any(%s::uuid[])"` which is equivalent of `IN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ANY(%s), for example in your case:

```
query_set = SomeModel.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM some_model_table where some_model_table.uuid = ANY(%s)", [list_of_uuids])
```